# Elasticsearch not responding after update (1.7.5 -> 2.3.1)

Tags: elasticsearch

I had Elasticsearch 1.7.5 and kopf plugin installed.
I've updated Elasticsearch to 2.3.1 and kopf to 2.0 and now it's not responding (Unable to connect error in browser). When I downgrade both to previous versions all work fine.
I run Ubuntu 14.04 + Apache2.

I checked [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) but did not find anything (tried various settings).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have ES installed locally on your workstation or on a remote server?

Comment: It's on remote server (I run VM on my Windows 10 machine).

Comment: The default setting in 2.0 and above ist to restrict access to requests coming from localhost. Could this be the reason? (you should be able to change this in the elasticsearch.yml config file)

Comment: and: did you check your indices with the [migration plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-migration) before updating to see if they are compatible with 2.3?

Comment: I've set http.cors.enabled=true and added my local domain to http.cors.allow-origin. No luck. What other settings should I set? I didn't check migration plugin as I don't care about data and I removed ES 1.7.5 and installed 2.3.1. Still the same. Curl on localhost:9200 works fine. Just remote access doesn't work.

Comment: When  `network.host` isn't set, it defaults to `_local_`. When you set it to `_site_` you should be able to access ES from within the same network.

Comment: @glaed thanks a lot. I updated my question with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

So finally I got to the point where all works fine again.

- you need to remember that it is yaml file so every character counts - I had unnecessary white spaces in it.
- **I added settings:**
- network.host: *site* (please remember to add _ before and after)
- http.cors.enabled: true
- http.cors.allow-origin: /https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?/
- and finally in my PHP code I set the host

> $client =
>   ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['http://domain.local:9200'])->build();

In command line I'm calling and getting positive result

> curl -XGET http://domain.local:9200/

Very, very big thank you for your help.